# Requests — always call raise_for_status

Tags: python, python-requests

I'd like to remove the repeated `x.raise_for_status()` lines:

```
x = requests.get(url1)
x.raise_for_status()

y = requests.delete(url2)
y.raise_for_status()

z = requests.post(url3, data={'foo': 'bar'})
z.raise_for_status()
```

How can I call `raise_for_status()` automatically?

Comment: I'm wondering if creating a decorated function and re-binding it to the 'requests' module is doable/suitable

Comment: @CédricVanRompay what you've described is called "monkey patching", and usually it's something to be avoided

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Create a session with a hook:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.hooks = {
    'response': lambda r, *args, **kwargs: r.raise_for_status()
}

x = session.get(url1)
y = session.delete(url2)
z = session.post(url3, data={'foo': 'bar'})
```

Comment: Real heroes don't wear capes